# strategy.exit order not executing

Tags: pine-script-v5

When the Entry criteria is met the script places a stop loss order calculated from a percentage of the current buy price. The strategy is to have an order for the stop loss placed at open so that if that price is ever met the order just fills. This should be done for both the long and short position conditions.

Even though the condition for a stop loss is seen in the strategy tester the strategy.exit never executes.

Script //

```
 
// Long Stop %
long_stop_percentage    = input.float(title ="Long Stop Loss (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.001, defval=1.0)
// this gets the last trade open price
long_current_buy_price     = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
// this calculates the value that a stop loss is activated from the initial buy price
long_stop_loss_price = long_current_buy_price - (long_current_buy_price * (long_stop_percentage/100))
 
// Short Stop %
short_stop_percentage   = input.float(title="Short Stop Loss (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.001, defval=1.0)
// this gets the last trade open price
short_last_buy_price    = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
// this calculates the value that a stop loss is activated from the initial buy price
short_stop_loss_price   = short_last_buy_price + (short_last_buy_price * (short_stop_percentage/100))
  
//===========================================================================================================================
//=============================================== Script Trade Entry  =======================================================
//===========================================================================================================================
    // Long Position
// the condition that needs to be met to enter a trade position
if ta.crossover(bb_src,bb_lower) and strategy.position_size==0 and entry_date_constraint
    strategy.entry("EL", strategy.long, comment = long_enter_comment)
    strategy.exit("xSL", from_entry="EL", stop = long_stop_loss_price)
    

     // Short Position
// the condition that needs to be met to enter a trade position
if ta.crossunder(bb_src,bb_upper) and strategy.position_size==0 and entry_date_constraint
    strategy.entry("ES", strategy.short, comment = short_enter_comment)
    strategy.exit("xSS", from_entry="ES", stop = short_stop_loss_price)
 
.....

I have tried to adjust the percentages for the stop loss and the trailing profit take.
Even though I have done that the orders dont stop loss and trailing profit properly.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your strategy.exit, you should try use limit instead of stop :
limit should be used to exit market position at the specified price (or better)
Your code should be :

```
// Long Stop %
// ...

// Long Position
// the condition that needs to be met to enter a trade position
if ta.crossover(bb_src,bb_lower) and strategy.position_size==0 and entry_date_constraint
    strategy.entry("EL", strategy.long, comment = long_enter_comment)
    strategy.exit("xSL", from_entry="EL", limit = long_stop_loss_price)


// Short Position
// the condition that needs to be met to enter a trade position
if ta.crossunder(bb_src,bb_upper) and strategy.position_size==0 and entry_date_constraint
    strategy.entry("ES", strategy.short, comment = short_enter_comment)
    strategy.exit("xSS", from_entry="ES", limit = short_stop_loss_price)

// ...
```